# Bugsnag unhandled error not sent for iOS app

Tags: bugsnag

I am having trouble getting crash report in my Bugsnag dashboard. I followed [Bugsnag doc](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/ios/) and tried to `fatalError()` on one of my ViewController and it seems like it does not work. By the way, `Bugsnag.notifyError(NSError(domain:"com.example", code:408, userInfo:nil))` seems working. There is not really meaningful code to provide to get the answer because what I tried is pretty trivial. Created an app, installed Bugsnag with cocoapod, disabled bitcode part as stated in the doc (installed the plugin that uploads dSYM file), and crashed the app on purpose.

Any help will be appreciated. I am frustrated to get crash report tool on my app. I have tried Firebase crash reporting tool and did not succeed too. T.,T

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the debugger attached? a `fatalError` will not report if the debugger is attached.

Additionally, you'll need to restart your app after a crash in order to send it in.

Hope that helps!